# Continuity of absolutely continuous joint probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, random-variables, multiple-integral

Let $X$ be an absolutely continuous random variable, i.e., the cumulative distribution function is given by
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\,dt$$
for some nonnegative (integrable) function $f$. Then it is easy to show using calculus that $F$ is continuous.

Now, let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that the joint cumulative distribution function is given by
$$F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^yf(s,t)\,ds\,dt$$
for some nonnegative (integrable) function $f(x,y)$.  Then does it follow that $F$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly does. For any integrable function $f$ on any measure space $\int_A |f|d\mu \to 0$ as $\mu (A) \to 0$. Continuity of your function follows easily from this.

You can also prove this using DCT and sequential definition of continuity.
Suppose $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$. Then $\int 1_{\{(t,s):t \leq x_n, s\leq y_n\}} f(t,s)dtst \to \int 1_{\{(t,s):t \leq x, s\leq y\}} f(t,s)dtst $ because the integrand is dominated by $|f(t,s)|$ which is integrable and the intergand converges a.e. to $f(t,s)$. Note that $\iint |f(t,s)|dtst=(\int |f(t)|dt)^{2}<\infty$ by Tonelli's Theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very weak on measure theory; do you mean $\mu((-\infty,x+\delta)\times(-\infty,y+\delta)\backslash(-\infty,x)\times(-\infty,y))\to0$ as $\delta\to0$ ? Can the area of an infinite strip go to zero by making it thinner?

Comment: I would appreciate a little more detailed proof...

Comment: @ashpool I have given details for the second  method.